# Maven dependency “Cannot resolve symbol VectorAssembler'” in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA cannot import Spark mllib, when I added dependency in maven. With other parts of Spark no problems. In project Structure -> Libraries spark mllib is present.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler; -> Cannot resolve symbol 'VectorAssembler'
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcthf.png)

I tried refreshing maven and clearing folder with repositories of maven. Nothing helped.

Comment: Try changing the version of mllib to 3.0.1

Comment: I tried many versions of mllib, result the same.

Comment: I think `<scope>runtime</scope>` is not supposed to be there.

Comment: Its true, but why this scope registered in maven. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib_2.12/3.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified mllib dependency as `runtime` - this means that dependency is required for execution, but not for compilation, so it won't be put into classpath for compiling your code.  See this [blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/mastering-maven-dependency-basics) for description of of different scopes available in Maven.

Replace all spark dependencies (`mllib`, `core`, `sql`) with just single dependency (also remove hadoop dependencies):

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-mllib_${spark.scala.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

where variables are defined as

```xml
  <properties>
    <spark.version>3.0.1</spark.version>
    <spark.scala.version>2.12</spark.scala.version>
  </properties>
```